# Issue when using SQL query in excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel-2010

I have the following sql, which works on http://sqlfiddle.com/. However I am trying to use it within MS Sql in excel. Any ideas why this doesn't work in excel and what I need to change? Many thanks :)

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(colA DATE, colB INT, colC TEXT);

INSERT INTO table1(colA, colB, colC) VALUES ("2016-01-01", "1", "C1");
INSERT INTO table1(colA, colB, colC) VALUES ("2016-01-02", "2", "C2");

CREATE TABLE table2(colD DATE, colE INT, colF TEXT);

INSERT INTO table2(colD, colE, colF) VALUES ("2016-01-03", "3", "F1");
INSERT INTO table2(colD, colE, colF) VALUES ("2016-01-04", "4", "F2");
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT colA, 
       colB, 
       (CASE When colA > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '9' MONTH then '+9 Months'
             When colA > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6' MONTH then '6 Months'
             When colA > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '4' MONTH then '4 Months'
             When colA > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '2' MONTH then '2 Months'
        END) AS colG 
FROM (SELECT colA, colB FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT colD, colE FROM table2
     ) t;
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd advice you to change `colC` to `VARCHAR` since `TEXT` is deprecated and will be dropped in further SQL Server releases. Perhaps that wil solve your issue.

Now secondly, your query doesn't work at all, perhaps you have selected different RDBMS in SQL Fiddle. There's no such thing as INTERVAL in SQL Server, you should use `DATEDIFF` function.

This is correct statement.

```
SELECT colA
    , colB
    , CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, colA, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > '9'THEN '+9 Months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, colA, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > '6' THEN '6 Months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, colA, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > '4' THEN '4 Months'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, colA, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > '2' THEN '2 Months'
    END AS colG
FROM (
    SELECT colA, colB
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT colD, colE
    FROM table2
    ) AS T;
```